Semantic Release GitHub action cannot publish changes because of protected branch
In my GitHub repository, I configured Semantic Release action:
name: Semantic Release

on:
    push:
        branches: [main]

jobs:
    release:
        name: Release version
        permissions:
            contents: write

        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
              with:
                  token: ${{ secrets.SEMANTIC_RELEASE_GH_TOKEN }}

            - name: Setup Node
              uses: actions/setup-node@v4
              with:
                  node-version-file: '.nvmrc'

            - name: Semantic Release
              uses: cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4.1.0
              with:
                  extra_plugins: |
                      @semantic-release/changelog
                      @semantic-release/commit-analyzer
                      @semantic-release/git
                      @semantic-release/npm
              env:
                  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SEMANTIC_RELEASE_GH_TOKEN }}


And my release.config.cjs file is:
const config = {
    branches: ['main'],
    repositoryUrl: 'git+https://github.com/tal-rofe/demo',
    plugins: [
        [
            '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
            {
                preset: 'angular',
                releaseRules: [
                    { type: 'feat', release: 'minor' },
                    { type: 'fix', release: 'patch' },
                    { type: 'perf', release: 'patch' },
                    { type: 'breaking', release: 'major' },
                ],
            },
        ],
        '@semantic-release/release-notes-generator',
        '@semantic-release/changelog',
        '@semantic-release/git',
        '@semantic-release/github',
        ['@semantic-release/npm', { npmPublish: false }],
    ],
};

module.exports = config;

I configured a protected branch on main branch with option "Require status checks to pass before merging" marked. Then the action fails with an error:
  stderr: 'remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/main.        \n' +
    'remote: error: 9 of 9 required status checks are expected.        \n' +
    'To https://github.com/tal-rofe/demo\n' +
    ' ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (protected branch hook declined)\n' +
    "error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/tal-rofe/demo'",

I configured my SEMANTIC_RELEASE_GH_TOKEN because I know that once I delete the protected branch, the action succeeds.
